# Ways to nest react apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way to "nest" react apps?
I know you can't directly nest them since it's only possible to have one package.json in the hierarchy.
Using an iframe will of course work but is undesirable.
Is there a way to run app 2 "separately" but still have it be shown within app 1?
Or can you turn app 2(App.js) into a component and go the whole compile/transpile, bundle, npm route?
And then have it running on app 1's instance of react?
Or would it be too complex to turn an app into a component because of all dependencies?

Would be great to get some input and hear possible solutions from you clever people.

Comment: You just described Micro-frontend. You can Google to read more about it and find out the best practices.

Comment: What does "best" mean to you? You'll need to be more clear about the requirements a valid solution needs to meet.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Well since I'm not too familiar with this, "best" means something that works but isn't an iframe.

Comment: Just import the inner App.js in the component of the outer app that you want to nest it, then use JSX like normal? I don't see why that wouldn't work. One app can be made an npm dependency of the another.

Comment: Although things might get more complicated if either app uses libraries that depend on "global" context provider components.